# How can I list all the git user configurations that were sent since git was installed?

Tags: git, git-config

I would like to list all the git configuration settings that the user set since git was installed.

I don't know any names or values of the configuration settings.

(In my case I want to find out what causes a particular git behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The git configuration settings are stored in `~/.gitconfig` file.

The file content looks like this:

```
[user]
        name = My Name
        email = myemail@adress.com
[color]
       ui = true
[push]
        default = matching
```

---

To output the configuration settings run this:

```
git config --list
```

or

```
git config --l
```